# How do I resolve unable to connect to mysql using WorkBench (Your connection attempt failed) issue

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04, failed-to-connect

This is a new install from scratch - target config is a LAMP server.  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is installed.  Apache2 installed.  Mysql installed.  Have not done PHP yet - wanted to get mysql working before I complicate things further.

New server is at IP 10.1.1.14 on a private network.  I have tried accessing mysql server using mysql Workbench 6.3 community running on MacOS Mojave (10.14).  Unable to connect.  Message is:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'rlxxxx@10.1.1.14' from your host to server at 10.1.1.14:3306:  SSL connection error: unknown error number
```

I also tried to use mysql client on a working RaspberryPi (IP 10.1.1.19) with command

```
mysql -u rlxxxx -h 10.1.1.14 -p
```

and received message:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.1.1.14' (110)
```

So clearly I have something basic wrong.

Back on mysql server (10.1.1.14) I have tried a few different bind settings in the file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf - started with the usual bind=127.0.0.1, also tried bind=0.0.0.0, and bind=10.1.1.14 (as suggested by one thread).  Makes no difference.  Same result.

```
mysql reports `Server version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 (Ubuntu)`.
```

So some basic diags...

```
?sudo ps wwaux | grep -i sql
mysql       2825  4.2 10.2 2069832 358232 ?      Ssl  06:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld

?sudo netstat -plutn | grep -i sql
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.14:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2825/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      2825/mysqld  

?systemctl status mysql
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-18 06:37:18 UTC; 43s ago
  Process: 2800 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 2825 (mysqld)
    Status: "Server is operational"
    Tasks: 39 (limit: 3935)
    Memory: 332.6M
    CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
            └─2825 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 18 06:37:16 svr4 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 18 06:37:18 svr4 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.

?sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp (Apache)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp (Apache (v6))       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

(yes, this is quite open right now... I am getting desperate)

And finally... from mysql

```
>select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| rlxxxx           | %         |
| rlxxxx           | 10.1.1.14 |
| root             | 10.1.1.14 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| rlxxxx           | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

If I ssh into 10.1.1.14, then either

```
mysql -u rlxxxx -p

mysql -u rlxxxx -h 10.1.1.14 -p
```

then they work fine, as you'd expect.

Any guidance on where I have gone wrong much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid anyone spending unnecessary time on this, I think I have discovered the issue.  May also help others that experience the same problem.

I believe that I was using an incompatible version of mysql Workbench (on my Mac) - it was used to talk to an older version of mysql server on my old test Raspberry Pi, which (coincidentally) is the same reason the Pi would not connect to the new Ubuntu server either.

Upgraded Workbench to 8.0 on my Mac, and it all just worked.

**Mysql version 8 requires Workbench version 8.**

That doesn't mean I have not made other errors - if you look through this and find anything, I'd be grateful if you'd let me know.  Otherwise, I'll keep moving forward.